# Using elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman with cofactor key for generating symmetric key

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, diffie-hellman

I am new to ECDH and wanted to generate the a secret key in Java. I wanted to use Elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman with cofactor key derivation. I'm using the P-256 curve for the elliptic curve operations. I'm planning to use the resulting secret as the symmetric key for my block cipher.

I have been working on this, and have the below working sample. This generates the secret key.

```
Provider BC = new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider();
ProviderList.newList(BC);
ECParameterSpec ecSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("P-256");   
KeyPairGenerator g = (KeyPairGenerator) KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
            "ECDH",BC);
g.initialize(ecSpec, new SecureRandom());

KeyPair aKeyPair = g.generateKeyPair();

KeyAgreement aKeyAgree = KeyAgreement.getInstance("ECDH", BC);

aKeyAgree.init(aKeyPair.getPrivate());

KeyPair bKeyPair = g.generateKeyPair();

KeyAgreement bKeyAgree = KeyAgreement.getInstance("ECDH", BC);

bKeyAgree.init(bKeyPair.getPrivate());

aKeyAgree.doPhase(bKeyPair.getPublic(), true);
bKeyAgree.doPhase(aKeyPair.getPublic(), true);

byte[] aSecret = aKeyAgree.generateSecret();
byte[] bSecret = bKeyAgree.generateSecret();

System.out.println(new String(aSecret));
System.out.println(new String(bSecret));
```

I am afraid that I am using an ephemeral private and public key instead of static keys. Please tell me how I can generate the secret key using a static private and public key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make static keys by simply storing them instead of generating them each time. You may have to use [`ECDHCBasicAgreement`](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jonah/bc/org/bouncycastle/crypto/agreement/ECDHCBasicAgreement.html) (note the additional C) to perform cofactor multiplication.

Note that you *should* perform a KBKDF over the secret to generate symmetric keys.

Comment: @ Owlstead thanks for your quick reply. Could you please let me know a bit more on the cofactor mutiplication in Java for the same

Comment: Not really, except that I don't *think* it is supported out of the box. Hence the reference to the special class in the BC lightweight (direct) API.

Comment: Wanted to use KDF as suggested by Owlstead Any info on KDF using sha-256 implementaions on java or bouncy castle.Didnt find much info even after long hours of trying

Comment: There should be a HKDF implementation for Java in Bouncy Castle. Again, this is not so much part of a provider then part of the lightweight API. The NIST SP 800-108 defined ones should be there as well (I should know, I've created the initial implementation for them).

Comment: I have tried my hand at HKDF implemention.And have a few questions there.PFB the link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889923/symmetric-key-generation-after-ecdhc-using-kdf-with-sha-256

Comment: @owlstead...I am facing some issues while storing the static values. Please have a look :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933804/creating-static-private-and-public-key-for-ecdhc.